# How do I get navigation and state in bottom tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

I am using [react native bottom navigation 6](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator). I want to get the navigation and state but it returns undefined.

```
export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabBar} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

/**
 * A bottom tab navigator displays tab buttons on the bottom of the display to switch screens.
 * https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator
 */
```

**This here returns null** ***({ navigation, state,descriptors }: BottomTabBarProp)***
I wanted to use the state.index to get the current tab and show a different icon/svg. My alternative is to use focused.

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

const BottomTabBar = ({ navigation, state,descriptors }: BottomTabBarProps) => (
  <>
  <BottomTab.Navigator 
  initialRouteName="Feed"
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.activeNavIcon,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.inactiveNavIcon
  }}
>
  <BottomTab.Screen
    name="Feed"
    component={FeedNavigator}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
        focused ?
          <HomeActive width={size} height={size} color={color} />
          : <Home width={size} height={size} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
  />

 
  <BottomTab.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={ProfileNavigator}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused  }) => (
        focused ?
        <ProfileActive width={size} height={size} color={color} />
        : <Profile width={size} height={size} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</BottomTab.Navigator>
  </>
);
```

Comment: You are rendering a navigator as bottom tab bar or what are you trying to do? It's strange to expect `BottomTabBarProps` in a regular component. They are available only in a custom bottom tab bar specified in the `tabBar` prop of the tab navigator.

Comment: "show a different icon/svg" where do you want to show a different icon?

Comment: Just want to use the navigation and state. if state==0 ?<Icon1/>:<Icon2/>

Answer (score 1):

As you are using functional component. I would recommend to use Hooks provided by `react-navigation`.

### useNavigation

[Link to Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation)

### useNavigationState

[Link to Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state)

```
const BottomTabBar = () => {

   const navigation = useNavigation()
  
   return (
     <>
     <BottomTab.Navigator 
       initialRouteName="Feed"
       screenOptions={{
         tabBarShowLabel: false,
         tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.activeNavIcon,
         tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.inactiveNavIcon
       }}
     />
  ...............
  ...............
  ..............
>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I'm confused where do I put const routesIndex = useNavigationState(state => state.index); I get hook error

Comment: @VincentDaveNavaresTe i have updated my answer, please check it.   Please upvote and accept my answer if its solves your problem

Comment: I am using this  const routesIndex = useNavigationState(state => state.index); but for some reason it is always returning 1. Wanted to know which tab is currently active

Comment: It is getting the stack state not the bottom nav. Any ideas how to get bottom nav state?

Comment: you cannot get State of BottomNav from same component, You can only get BottomState from its child components.